# foreach php nested array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

How foreach this array to `< a href="path-to-jpg-file">name< /a>`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => 01-siena-rosso-new.jpg
                [1] => Siena Rosso
            )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 02-siena-noce-new.jpg
            [1] => Siena Noce
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 03-zloty-dab.jpg
            [1] => Złoty Dąb
        )
)
```

Comment: Post your tried code.

Answer (score 6):

Try loop like this:-

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    echo '<a href="'.$value[0].'">'.$value[1].'</a>';
}
```

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/98124)

Comment: Super! 01 i part filename

Comment: @Roopendra actually the OP said like `< a href="path-to-jpg-file">name< /a>`. Thats why I said

Comment: @ling.s yes its same.

Comment: @Roopendra not same. You code returns `<a href="01-siena-rosso-new.jpg">`

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Roopendras, you just need preg_replace:

```
foreach($array as $value) {
    echo '<a href="'.preg_replace('/^\d\d-/','',$value[0]).'">'.$value[1].'</a>';
}
```